# jQuery this.text not working in IE after live event

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, live, this

I am currently trying to update my website with some jQuery functions. As allways with web development IE is being a pain.

I have an autosuggestion list that looks like this:

```
<div id="suggestionBox">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="entry" style="display:block;" href="#">somesuggestion</a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul
</div>
```

Of course, the suggestions are gained from a server, so I use a load() function every time the input field is changed. This works all fine.
The problem is, I want the input field to be completed when a suggestion is clicked.
I use the following code for that:

```
$(".entry").live('click', function() {
    $("#" + $("#suggestionBox").data('input')).val(this.text);
    //and some more stuff
});
```

The data field for the suggestionBox is set when the input field gets focus.

It works perfectly fine in Chrome, and FireFox but not in IE.
this.text in the above code returns undefined.

I have no clue why this shouldn't work for IE. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you meaning to select a field that has the ID designated by an item of data on the element `#suggestionBox`? That's a trifle unorthodox...

Comment: No I need to reaplcae the value of the input field with whatever the value of the clicked suggestion was. And since the input field doesn't have focus anymore once you click the suggestion I just pass the input field ID on to the suggestionbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you use jQuery?

```
$(this).text()
```

[An `a` element has no `text` property in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535173(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Hah I was so close! I tried $(this).text 
Thank you and the person below or above (He's below this post for me)!

Comment: you mean the person above.. ;)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, @lordstyx: *above*, *below* is totally irrelevant and changes with the view you select for the answers (and is random if you sort by votes and answers have the same vote count). Naming answers by the person who created it is much better.

Comment: @Felix I know (apart of randomness of same vote count!) was just kidding. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Oh, and just for the record, I answered first. :)

Comment: @Felix doesn't look random - you're currently on top on every refresh, maybe it was changed to alphabetical sort? (F comes before J :)) @Jacob I know how you feel! :p

Comment: Anyway, Thank you both Jacob Relkin an Felix Kling

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Is this a joke again? ;) The accepted answer is always on top (als long as the vote is > 0 (not sure about that, maybe it is always on top)).

Comment: @Felix: ugh.. let's say it was a joke. :D (yeah, always on top, now I recall seeing answer with -2 on top of answer with 5 when sorting by votes as it was accepted)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, Hmm, you're from Israel? Cool!

Comment: @Jacob - Israel indeed! Glad you find it cool, though ATM your place is much much cooler.. (~0°C vs. ~20°C ;))

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Ha, well, I did a semester there and I've been there many times on vacation. :-)

Comment: @Jacob that's really cool - one of my friends is also long time member here (didn't know that before I joined :/) we can arrange "SO meeting" over some beer when you next arrive. :-P

Answer (score 2):

You need to use jQuery's [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function, not property, since the underlying DOM property is browser-specific:

```
$("#" + $("#suggestionBox").data('input')).val($(this).text());
```